# Why does my element not show as having it's attribute changed when I see the change in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="button accessLink" id="loginLink" data-action="Login" 
data-dialog="access" data-disabled="no" data-entity="n/a" 
data-href="/User/Access/Login" title="Login" 
style="-webkit-user-select: none;" data-title="Login">Login</div>
```

I have some code and when I step through the debugger I see the following get 
executed with $(targetSelector) set to #loginLink.

```
$(targetSelector).attr('data-disabled', 'yes');
```

When I check again with the chrome developer tools then I see:

```
<div class="button accessLink" id="loginLink" data-action="Login" 
data-dialog="access" data-disabled="no" data-entity="n/a" 
data-href="/User/Access/Login" title="Login" 
style="-webkit-user-select: none;" data-title="Login">Login</div>
```

Can someone explain why data-disabled does not seem to change?

Comment: You probably did'nt change it then, as it seems to be working for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fd9un/3/). jQuery has it's own `data()` function to deal with data attributes btw.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QWSXF/ well, my one also working and DOM is updated in chrome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `debugger` might not be `refreshing` changed values or you might be missing something, you need to print them to see the change e.g using alert. You statement seems correct and is changing the attribute.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6eHr/)**

```
$('#loginLink').attr('data-disabled', 'yes');    
alert($('#loginLink').attr('data-disabled'));
```

You are try​ing to change data attribute and jQuery gives you data() function to set and get the data attributes so you would using data() instead of attr().

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6eHr/1/)**

```
$('#loginLink').data('disabled', 'yes');
alert($('#loginLink').data('disabled'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just try like this

```
   $('#loginLink').data('disabled', 'yes');
```